# automapper exception when mapping TableEntity dictionary - must resolve to top-level member

Tags: c#, automapper

Using a dictionary `TableEntity` to a POCO, I get the following error

`Expression 'dest => dest.get_Item(\"DeviceName\")' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. You can use ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead. (Parameter 'lambdaExpression')`

I have a DTO as below:

```
public class Enrollment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset InitiatedOn { get; set; }
    public AttestationStatus Status { get; set; } = AttestationStatus.Pending;
    public string? KeyReleasedToAddress { get; set; }
}

public enum AttestationStatus { Pending = 0, Approved = 1, Rejected = 2 }
```

And use the [`TableEntity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableentity?view=azure-dotnet) class where one can map its properties via an indexer:

```
public partial class TableEntity : IDictionary<string, object>
{
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the entity's property, given the name of the property.</summary>
    /// <param name="key">A string containing the name of the property.</param>
    /// <returns>The property value typed as an object.</returns>
    public object this[string key]
    {
        get { return GetValue(key); }
        set { SetValue(key, value); }
    }

    /* snip */
 }
```

I am trying to use the mapper below:

```
private static readonly IMapper Mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Enrollment, TableEntity>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.RowKey, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id.ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest["DeviceName"], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DeviceName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest["InitiatedOn"], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InitiatedOn))
            .ForMember(dest => dest["Status"], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Status.ToString()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest["KeyReleasedToAddress"], opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.KeyReleasedToAddress))
            .ReverseMap()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Guid.Parse(src.RowKey)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Enum.Parse<AttestationStatus>(src.GetString("Status"))));
    })
    .CreateMapper();
```

And map with the below, which is where the exception is thrown:

```
public async Task<Enrollment?> Get(Guid tenant, Guid enrollment, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var entry = await tableClient.GetEntityAsync<TableEntity>(
                                        tenant.ToString(),
                                        enrollment.ToString(),
                                        cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    return entry == null ? null : Mapper.Map<TableEntity, Enrollment>(entry);
}
```

Help much appreciated on how I would map to this object accessed via indexers, and vice-versa back the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can map a dictionary to an object without explicitly specifying an indexer in mapper profile

```
void Test()
{
    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { }).CreateMapper();
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "Id", 1 },
        { "Description", "test" }
    };

    var product = mapper.Map<Product>(dictionary);

    Assert.IsNotNull(product);
    Assert.AreEqual(product.Id, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(product.Description, "test");
}

class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```